# Modifying Listbox Collection Causes Syntax Error

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I'm using Kendo-UI's Listbox but whenever I attempt to add/remove items in my datasource it gives me the following syntax error in my jQuery.min file:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <li class='k-item' role='option' aria-selected='false'>My Item</li>
```

This is my markup:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="roles-permissions-edit">
    <div class="hpanel hblue">
        <div class="panel-heading hbuilt">
            Permissions - <span data-bind="text: roleName"></span>
            <div class="panel-tools">
                <a class="showhide"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <a class="k-button btn-xs" href="#/">
                            <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i>
                            Roles
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="role-permissions-available">Available</label>
                        <select id="role-permissions-available"></select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="role-permissions-selected">Selected</label>
                        <select id="role-permissions-selected"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                        <button type="button" class="k-button" data-bind="click: save">Save</button>
                        <button type="button" class="k-button" data-bind="click: reset">Reset</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

And this is how I'm initializing the widget:

```
var available = $("#role-permissions-available").data("kendoListBox");
var selected = $("#role-permissions-selected").data("kendoListBox");
var availableDataSource = [];
var selectedDataSource = [];

var filter = {
    RoleId: _viewModel.edit.roleId
};

_viewModel.permissionDataSource.read(filter).then(function () {
    var data = _viewModel.permissionDataSource.data();
    var roleHasSystemAction = function (systemActionId) {
        return data.filter(function (item) {
            return item.SystemActionId === systemActionId;
        }).length > 0;
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < _viewModel.systemActions.length; i++) {
        var systemAction = _viewModel.systemActions[i];

        if (roleHasSystemAction(systemAction.SystemActionId)) {
            selectedDataSource.push(systemAction);
        } else {
            availableDataSource.push(systemAction);
        }
    }

    available.setDataSource(availableDataSource);
    selected.setDataSource(selectedDataSource);
});
```

To clarify, my widget initializes just fine and the data in my datasource looks just fine. The issue comes from trying to add/remove items between the ListBox widgets.

**Update**
This was resolved fairly quickly and I feel a bit silly that I didn't look at  this first. The version of jQuery that I was using was jQuery v1.9.1. Upgrading it fixed the issue.

**Update #2** I've submitted a bug on [github here](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/5494) because according to the documentation, it should be compatible will jQuery v1.9.1.